# LogNormal Distribution

Tags: plotting

I was replaying the next plot in Mathematica

[image]

For that I used the next code line

```
Plot[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[18.3, 8.8], x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 40},
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 PlotLabel -> "Times distribution ", 
 FrameLabel -> {"days", "probability"}]
```

But the plot is very different:

[image: What is it happening?]
What is it happening?

Comment: You've posted a picture with different plot labels. When I run that code I get a plot that looks reasonably good on 12.1.1 Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dist = LogNormalDistribution[m, s];
```

Given the mean and standard deviation, the underlying parameters `{m, s}` are

```
param = NSolve[{Mean[dist] == 183/10,
    StandardDeviation[dist] == 88/10, s > 0},
   {m, s}, Reals][[1]]

(* {m -> 2.80289, s -> 0.456094} *)

Plot[PDF[dist /. param, x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 40},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> Blue,
 PlotLabel -> "Times distribution ",
 FrameLabel -> {"days", "probability"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is likely to not be a good question. But, LogNormalDistribution takes mean and standard deviation. Why do you have to solve for them rather than putting the provided ones directly in?

Comment: @PaulCommentary - The parameters of the lognormal distribution are the mean and standard deviation of the **normal distribution** from which the lognormal distribution is derived. The mean and standard deviation of the data are what is given, and correspond to the mean and standard deviation of the lognormal distribution, i.e,, `Mean[dist]` and `StandardDeviation[dist]`. Note that `Mean[dist] == E^(m + s^2/2)` and `StandardDeviation[dist] == Sqrt[E^(2*m + s^2)*(-1 + E^s^2)]`

Comment: Thanks. Should have figured that out. Appreciate clarification.

Comment: Thanks,now it is also clear for me.